# Custom validation code is not triggered immediately after leaving focus

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For my `asp.net MVC View`, I used validation annotation and custom validator to verify my fields.

In my `ViewModel`,

For a test,  I used

```
[StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "This is a test to check if validation appears after leaving textbox")]
[Display(Name = "Requestor First Name")]
[Required]
public string RequestorFirstName { get; set; }
```

In the View, when I type just a letter and leave the textbox focus, the error message appears for stringlength. I know that
client validation is working.

For my custom validator:

```
[FaceAmount]
public decimal CurrentFaceAmount { get; set; }
```

When I change the dollar amount in the `CurrentFaceAmount` field, it does not `IMMEDIATELY` fire off the custom validation code. Only
after hitting the Submit button, the break point is hit in the following code:

```
public class FaceAmount : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private string _dependentProperty;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            decimal val;
            var isNumeric = decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);

            if (isNumeric)
            {
                if (val > 0 && val < 100000)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Minimum Coverage Amount is $1000.00");
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

How can I fire this custom validation code after leaving the textbox focus?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a client-side validator that looks like this, courtesy of [Ode to Code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/23/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx):

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive
      .adapters.addSingleVal("greaterdate", "other");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterdate",
    function (val, element, other) {
        var modelPrefix = element.name.substr(
                            0, element.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        var otherVal = $("[name=" + modelPrefix + other + "]").val();
        if (val && otherVal) {
            if (Date.parse(val) <= Date.parse(otherVal)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

And link to it using IClientValidatable:

```
public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : 
                    ValidationAttribute, 
                    IClientValidatable 
{

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>
        GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
                                 ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("other", OtherProperty);
        rule.ValidationType = "greaterdate";
        yield return rule;
    }
```